# Dimensionality theorem irreps finite dimensional algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

For representations of finite groups it is known that the regular representation of a finite group is the direct sum of irreps, each with dimension equal to the multiplicity with which they appear. I assume the same does not hold for the algebra case since we can't really talk about conjugacy classes and the left action of an algebra on itself does not necessarily permute the basis elements of the algebra.

I do wonder whether there exists some (probably weaker) statement about the decomposition of the regular representation of irreps of a finite dimensional complex algebra?

Comment: Do we know something about the base field? That has an impact. For example if the algebra is a division algebra over its center, then the regular representation is irreducible. However, if the base field has a trivial Brauer group (e.g. it is algebraically closed), then no such division algebras exist. At another end we have for example algebras like $F[x]/(x^n)$, where the only irreducible representation has $x$ acting as zero. In between we have semisimple algebras. Those have [a Wedderburn decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Wedderburn_theorem).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, the field I'm interested in is C.

Comment: (cont'd) implying that the algebra is a direct sum of a matrix algebras (of varying sizes). This generalizes the case of simple matrix algebras $A=M_n(F)$ of square matrices. The only irrep of that has dimension $n$. Think: columns of size $n$ acted upon by $A$ via matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is any ring (and in particular any finite-dimensional complex algebra) then the regular representation of $A$ on itself by left multiplication has submodules consisting of exactly the left ideals, more or less by definition. It is completely reducible iff $A$ is [semisimple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_module), again more or less by definition, and for $A$ finite-dimensional over a field (or more generally for $A$ [Artinian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artinian_ring)) this occurs iff $A$ has vanishing [Jacobson radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_radical).

If $A$ is Artinian but does not have vanishing Jacobson radical then $A/J(A)$ is semisimple and is the maximal quotient with this property, and by the [Artin-Wedderburn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Wedderburn_theorem) it is a finite direct product of matrix rings $M_n(D)$ over division rings. In particular if $A$ is finite-dimensional over a field $k$ then $A/J(A)$ is a finite direct product of matrix rings over division $k$-algebras, so if $k$ is algebraically closed $A/J(A)$ is a finite direct product of matrix rings $M_n(k)$ over $k$.

In the case of semisimple algebras over an algebraically closed field $k$, each $d$-dimensional simple module $S$ corresponds to a matrix ring factor $M_d(k) = \text{End}_k(S)$ which, in terms of the left action of $A$ on itself consists of $d$ copies of $S$. A conceptual way to see this is that when $A$ is a semisimple module then the multiplicity of $S$ in $A$ is $\dim_k \text{Hom}_A(A, S)$, and we have $\text{Hom}_A(A, S) \cong S$ since $A$ is the free $A$-module. More generally, if $A$ is a semisimple ring and $S$ a simple module with endomorphism ring $\text{End}_A(S) \cong D$, corresponding to a matrix ring factor $M_d(D)$ in $A$, then the multiplicity of $S$ in $A$ is

$$\dim_D \text{Hom}_A(A, S) = \dim_D S = d.$$

So $S$ still occurs with multiplicity equal to its dimension but its dimension needs to be understood as a module over its endomorphism ring $D$ (which is a division ring by Schur's lemma).